# Regex expressions (“illegal escape character”)

Tags: regex

I am using regular expressions to finds `strings` like

> "override="/var/logs/TEST/" or "override="/var/logs/SAMPLE/" in a .xml
>   file.

I have this final `string` as pattern:

```
public final static String REGEX_LOGPATH="override=\"\/var\/logs\/([^\"]*)\/";
```

It works fine (i get BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) while running the project in NetBeans IDE), all strings are found. But when I attemp to compile the code to a .jar file, I get this error msg:

error: `illegal` escape character

```
public final static String REGEX_LOGPATH="override=\"\/var\/logs\/([^\"]*)\/";
```

Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to escape forwards slashes, as they are not special (escape-able) characters.

Comment: They are here `public final static String REGEX_LOGPATH="override=\"\/var\/logs\/([^\"]*)\/";`